# CALayer - remove from view

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, caanimation

I'm adding `CAShapeLayer` with some `CABasicAnimation`. I want to be able to remove the layer and draw it again but I can't succeed with this.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self drawLayer];
}

- (void)drawLayer {
    if (_alayer && _layer.superlayer) {
        [_alayer removeFromSuperlayer];
        _alayer = nil;
    }

    _alayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    _alayer.path = [self myPath].CGPath;
    _alayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    _alayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    _alayer.lineWidth = 2.f;
    _alayer.strokeStart = 0.f;
    _alayer.strokeEnd = 1.f;
    [self.layer addSublayer:_alayer];

    // animate
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    animation.duration = 2.f;
    animation.fromValue = @0.f;
    animation.toValue = @1.f;
    [_alayer addAnimation:animateStrokeEnd forKey:@"strokeEndAnimation"];
}
```

}

However a moment after calling `[self setNeedsDisplay];` even though it stops at the breakpoint in `drawLayer` method, the drawing doesn't disappear and animate in again. `alayer` is declared as `nonatomic, strong` property. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should not call [self drawLayer]; fromm drawRect: because it is called periodically. 
Use other viewDidLoad or call it from other method instead

Edited:

drawRect: should only be used for drawing, I don't know if it will even work if you add animation from there.

If you want it to disappear and appear, you should try to add delay using [self performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:].

I think changing hidden or opacity should suffice, you only need to removeAllAnimations to make sure no more animation attached to that layer.

However I think you should try other way than calling drawLayer from drawRect: because I don't it its good practice anyway.

Comment: This is intended behaviour. I want this to be redrawn with rest of things when the system requires to refresh the view (so calls drawRect:).

Answer (score 0):

The UIView has its own property [layer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW31) by default. Please try to change a variable name to shapeLayer or another one.

Comment: Well in my code it is called different, refactored code so it's more readable on SOF, but you're right, ivar I've presented here isn't the best idea. Anyway, this has nothing in common with my problem.